# JMeter Flexible file writer trying to save requestbody to a single cell in csv file

Tags: jmeter

With Jmeter I am trying to save the request body using the Flexible file writer in csv file format. The request body is  a json format something like this :

POST https://testurl

POST data :
{
"label" : test
}

The request body is getting saved to the file but not in a single cell. It is coming in multiple rows. How can I save the complete request body to one single cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as "cell" in CSV files so your question doesn't make a lot of sense

---

If your request body is multiline you might want to remove these line breaks before saving the request body, it can be done using i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
def requestBody = prev.getSamplerData().replaceAll('[\n\r]', '') 
vars.put('requestBody', requestBody)
```

[image]

You will need to declare this `requestBody` as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) in the *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=requestBody
```

and once done you will be able to access the value in the Flexible File Writer as `variable#0`

Answer (score 0):

[Filewriter csv][1]
Thanks for the response. When I try this I am seeing the requestdata like shown in the screenshot. And incase if there are multiple controllers the request body for all of them will be appended one after another in the same line.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9Hm.jpg